# External Domain to Database to Picture via JQuery

Tags: jquery, sql, database, embed, image

Is it possible to embed a jQuery script (that is located on my website) on a external domain, that will get its address, then search my database for it and then will displays a certain picture depending on a value in the database? If so, where do i start with it? I'm very new in jQuery.

Thanks in advance, Lachee

Comment: If I'm correctly understanding your question, the better way is this to be done serverside, using your project serverside language as PHP, ASP, Perl or another serverside language.

Comment: I see what you mean now, just link to a php that connects to my database and does that trippyness